# Spring system parameter is being ignored

Tags: spring, docker, environment, docker-container

I created my Dockerfile where I want to create a simple Spring Boot Webapp listening on a port.

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ENV port=123
#WORKDIR /workdir
ADD /target/docker-test-0.1.jar dockertest.jar
EXPOSE $port
RUN bash -c 'touch /dockertest.jar'
#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port","-jar","/dockertest.jar"]
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port
```

My webapps **application.properties** defines the following:

```
server.port=666
```

Starting my docker container via IntelliJ Docker Plugin I give it the parameter:

`port=555`

Running `docker inspect bootapp` (bootapp is the containers name) gives me following information about the port environment variable and the entrypoint:

```
 "Entrypoint" : [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "java -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port" ],
    "Env" : [ "port=555", ...],
```

And Spring Boots log says this:

```
2017-08-30 20:10:07.709  INFO 5 --- [main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 666 (http)
```

So the port defined in `application.properties` was not overwritten by a runtime parameter.

This tells me that `EXPOSE=$port` actually was able to be resolved but the variable in ENTRYPOINT wasn't.

I already changed ENTRYPOINT to shell form but that did not helped as you can see through my Dockerfile

Comment: Are you sure the env var isn't being resolved, what does it output if you change your entrypoint line to: `ENTRYPOINT echo java -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port`

Comment: You're right. I just figured out that the jvm is ignoring my `-Dserver.port` runtime parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The system variable was at the wrong place in the java execution command.
It has to be place before the `-jar` option.

**Wrong**

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port
```

**Right**

```
ENTRYPOINT java -Dserver.port=$port -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```